# android Serializable

Tags: android, android-intent, serializable

i have a class which implement Serializable.

when i'm adding an object from that class to the Intent extra and lunch an activity i have no problems.

but when i'm trying to add the object to an Intent lunched by a PedingIntent in a notificatoin bar, i the get the following error:

```
08-08 18:20:06.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object
```

this is my code:

```
        this.tickerText = sender.getName() + " Sent you a new message";
        CharSequence contentTitle = "New message from " + sender.getName();       
        CharSequence contentText = "Click to open";
        Intent chat = new Intent(context, Chat.class);      
        chat.putExtra(app.EXTRA_FACEBOOKUSER, sender);
        chat.putExtra(app.EXTRA_RESET_WAINTING_CHAT_MESSAGES, true);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, chat, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);      
        this.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
```

the sender variable class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;


public class FacebookUser implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name, gender, status;    
    private int id;
    private double distance, longitude, latitude;;
    private Drawable profilePicture;
    private boolean isFacebookFriend = false;

    public FacebookUser() {

    }

    public FacebookUser(int id, String name)    {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName(name);     
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Drawable getProfilePicture() {
        Drawable picture = profilePicture;
        if (picture != null)
            picture = profilePicture.getConstantState().newDrawable();
        return picture;
    }

    public void setProfilePicture(Drawable profilePicture) {
        this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public boolean isFacebookFriend() {
        return isFacebookFriend;
    }

    public void setFacebookFriend(boolean isFacebookFriend) {
        this.isFacebookFriend = isFacebookFriend;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the `Sender` class. In general, all of its members must either be `Serializable` or `transient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) is not `Serializable`. Try setting it to `transient` and to [handle the implications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/) of this accordingly in your code. Basically you have to deal with that the `Drawable` member will be null after de-serialization. You can hook into the serialization process with the `readObject` and `writeObject` methods as described in the above link to serialize it yourself.